# How can I add marker to google map embed api?

Tags: google-maps

I try to add google map embed api to my site. That like from documencation, like the following

```html
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

But, I don't know how to add marker to embed api. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Where do you want to add the marker?

Comment: @geocodezip I wan to add it in map that I embed to my site.

Comment: Where on the map do you want the marker to appear?

Comment: The Address I added to. In the above example **Space+Needle,Seattle+WA** place

Comment: [The posted code has a marker there for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. I tried the "directions" for a set of markers, seems to work. In my case it was an itinerary so it was reasonable.

```
iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=my key here&amp;origin=45.476112,-73.823152&amp;destination=45.800000,-73.823298&amp;mode=walking&amp;waypoints=45.47611153,-73.82315248|45.56712414,-73.82331277|45.6,-73.82318975|45.7,-73.83250646|45.8,-73.82329847&amp;center=45.47611153,-73.82315248&amp;zoom=14" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

If you happen to know how to get it to go fullscreen, I'd be grateful.